# How did Steve Rogers find this place?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

After the finale fight between Iron Man and Captain America, there is one scene where Captain America goes to The Raft in order to break his captured team-mates out of prison.

How did he learn the location of The Raft to get there in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first of the films two post-credits scenes, we see that;

> Steve Rogers and T'Challa are now on friendly terms with each other, with T'Challa even going so far as to help "store" Bucky Barnes until someone figures out a way to turn off his Hydra conditioning. Thanks to the fact that we see T'Challa follow Tony Stark to the place where the final fight takes place, we know that he knows where The Raft is.

As such, it could be that this character told Steve where it was, and maybe even helped him get there.

However, this is just one possibility. There are alternatives:

- Natasha Romanoff was very involved in the process of signing the Sokovia Accords, and as such she might be privvy to the location of The Raft (and even if she wasn't, she's an elite spy; it probably wouldn't take her too long to figure it out). She leaves Tony's side after attacking T'Challa during the airport sequence, and as such could have told Steve the location of The Raft.
- We know full well that Tony knows the location of The Raft thanks to seeing him visit it at one point. Although he and Steve don't exactly end the film on the best of terms, Tony seems receptive to Steve's letter at the end, and (more importantly) actively ignores Secretary of State Ross' phone call about a security breach at The Raft. It could be that Tony felt guilty about having so many of his friends imprisoned, and as such leaked the location of The Raft to Steve in order to break them out.

However, these are all just guesses based on what we see in the film. I doubt we will ever have a direct confirmation about how Steve found The Raft as ultimately, it doesn't matter. What matters is that he did find it.

Comment: It's not Tony as that letter was surprise for him , that means Cap is contacting him by letter first time after the fight.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Who says that Tony hadn't already decided to leak that information to Cap before he received the letter though?

Comment: Then we can speculated anything, even Sharon Carter or maybe the security guy or maybe ..............

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, we can; but these are the most likely options, which is why I posted them. And as I say in the answer itself; "*I doubt we will ever have a direct confirmation about how Steve found The Raft as ultimately, it doesn't matter. What matters is that he did find it.*"

Comment: I left the spoiler markup for the post-credit scene (though, even that should be completely unnecessary), but all the other spoiler blocks made *zero* sense given that the questions asks about *the end of the film*. Remember that your answer has to make sense without the spoiler markup, which it didn't.

Comment: @DrRDizzle But to me Sharon Carter made more sense then Tony

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sharon Carter had nothing to do with the Accords or the people that signed them. Her involvement in the story is minimal.

Comment: @DrRDizzle She stole there gadgets and costume. She knows stuff. Doesn't it depends on who can do it rather then there screen time in film?

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's true, but by that logic literally any character in the film or *Agents of SHIELD* or the Netflix shows could be the one who told Steve where The Raft is. I'm just listing what I believe to be the most likely explanations, and I don't think Sharon Carter is one.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Tony who literally tried to kill him is better contender then his own gf (Sharon Carter). She helped him in the film Civil War not some maybe-canon TV show. And if Sharon Carter can know where there gadgets and costume are and even easily steal them, then they why can't she know the place for Raft and told that to cap?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Tony didn't try to kill Steve, he tried to kill Bucky. And there is a big difference between Sharon knowing where Cap's SHIELD will be stored (she's the one who takes it into storage after all; we see her give Steve and Sam the receipts for their items) and knowing where a top secret facility for imprisoning super villains is located. Bear in mind that no-one on Team Cap even knew that the Raft existed before they were imprisoned there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39614/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-dr-r-dizzle).

Comment: @DrRDizzle well may be we cant judge that..